# Neo4j websocket connection timeout on Google Compute Engine

Tags: neo4j, configuration, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

I'm currently running Neo4j on Google Cloud with in a Compute Engine VM running Ubuntu. The `7474` port works as expected, however I'm receiving the following message when trying to connect to server:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://<ip>:7687/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I checked the `conf/neo4j.conf` for `dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687` and it's not commented out.

I checked the firewall, and there is a rule for port `7687`, so what else could cause this?

Thanks in advance for the help

**Update:**

I was able to use the `cypher-shell` from the VM's command line, which connects to `bolt://localhost:7687`

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Neo4j Browser or are you using a bolt driver ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both. the error message was from using Browser. the bolt driver didn't throw any error when I tried to send `MERGE` request, but the no data was saved into the database

Comment: If you want to use neo4j browser you can set the browser settings(on the left bottom side)  to not use bolt. As for bolt drivers I do not know... my guess is that it has to do something with firewall settings as you are able to connect locally and not non local... that brings me to another idea... Did you set the neo4j.conf to allow non-local connections ?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled in the noe4j.conf. I agree with you that it looks more like a firewall issue with the VM at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with neither GCP nor neo4j. The company where I work for has a firewall blocking the port, and that's why I wasn't able to connect to the database using the browser. Dataflow in Compute Engine had no problem connecting to neo4j.